# How to make API calls to openAI service from snowpark worksheet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a review analysis pipeline in python that I'm trying to run in Snowpark worksheet. The code breaks the moment API call to openAI service is made. Not even one API call is made successfully, and the error is thrown right away. I'm using openAI package to make all the calls.

The line 64 in the traceback is this line of code:

```
response = openai.Completion.create(engine="text-davinci-003", prompt=prompt, max_tokens=m_tokens, n=1,stop=None,temperature=0)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/203e20e0c0903ba4b07cf1a173ed96b6393b76dc98997f79a03471b36222fcf9/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 363, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff64769640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 826, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 826, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openai.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff64769640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openai/api_requestor.py", line 516, in request_raw
    result = _thread_context.session.request(
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 520, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openai.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff64769640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Worksheet, line 479, in main
  Worksheet, line 404, in run_pipeline
  Worksheet, line 378, in analyze_reviews_batch
  Worksheet, line 64, in analyze_reviews
  File "openai/api_resources/completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
  File "openai/api_requestor.py", line 216, in request
    result = self.request_raw(
  File "openai/api_requestor.py", line 529, in request_raw
    raise error.APIConnectionError(
openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openai.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff64769640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

I tried to look for firewall settings in Snowpark, but there isn't any such option. Under the hood AWS is being used. Could it be related to network settings of AWS? If so, how to resolve it?

Comment: [External Network Access For Snowpark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXnjvyeb-Q8)

Comment: To add to what @LukaszSzozda mentioned, the external network access is currently in preview therefore you will need to reach your Snowflake Account team to be part of the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Today in general you do not have an external network access in Snowflake.

Currently you may think only of external functions https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.

In the future such call will be possible - External Network Access For Snowpark https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXnjvyeb-Q8.